# Charging a 36V battery set with a 255W solar panel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell

I have directly connected a 255W solar panel (with Vmpp of 49.5V but can peak at 56V in full sun at mid-day) to the 36V battery set of my golf cart.  This seems to have been working fine for months, as I am a light user of the golf cart (a few miles per day) in a sunny state.  In other words, I have been able go for months without connecting to the grid.  However, my research certainly leads me to believe that there is a risk of overcharging (if there isn't a good balance between my driving and the sun-hours, I pressume).  My question is whether the overcharging would be due to excessive Amps or excessive Volts?  (depending on the answer, I may fashion the correct protection).

Comment: Have you found any useful information; or was the answer helpful?  If so, its typically practice to 'accept' it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info, e.g. battery specs.  I would almost certainly guess the batteries can handle much more input current than the panel will ever be able to put out, though.  You'd be concerned about overvoltage.

From this [SO Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80804/charging-12v-batteries-with-direct-connection-to-20v-solar-panels) (referring to a single 12V, but you can extend it here):

"The maximum is typically around 14.4V to 14.8V at 21C temperature. **If the maximum is exceeded for minutes to hours, the battery will be permanently damaged.** The damage occurs around the same time that flammable gas is generated and vented, so there is a risk of gas explosion near the battery.

Your setup would require constant monitoring, especially if the load is disconnected or turned off. Check the voltage every hour, and **disconnect the solar panel as the voltage approaches the maximum**.

To find the maximum voltage, check the manufacturer's label or datasheet for the battery." (Emphasis added)

Based on the three stages of 36V battery charging described [here](http://www.chargingchargers.com/tutorials/36-volt-charger.html), it seems a reasonable maximum voltage for your setup might be 40.5V.  I don't know your batteries though, and I am also assuming that you are using a lead-acid chemistry.